# Google Assistant expose incoming webhook

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible to create a webhook on the google assistant that I can http post data to for it to broadcast?

I want to make a real simple application where I can send tweets from specific users to the assistant to read out loud.

Comment: I too looked for something similar but was unable to find a solution.  My best belief is that an assistant will only speak when spoken to.  I couldn't find any story that would speak because of unsolicited actions.  The best I could find is a push notification which causes a dialog box to appear if we have a display.  In the end I wrote a Text To Speech app that I ran on a Raspberry Pi that subscribes to text using PubSub.

Comment: @kolban interesting. I saw someone wrote a npm package that uses the casting API to cast text to the assistant. The downside is it has to be ran on the same network. I can setup a raspberry pi to act as a gateway from the outside to run the program but I was just hoping for a simple webhook

Answer (score 0):

That is a "yes, but" question. The Actions platform allows you to send notifications to users whom you have previously queried for permission and who have consented. When they pull down the notification and tap on it, your Action runs a special intent whose name was specified at the time you ask for permission. Details are here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications